# Changing the "current" class of an element only works if the element has no href

Tags: html, jquery, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to make a navigation bar that has some CSS code for the current tab and it only works for the elements that don't have a page to load.

This is my HTML code:

```
<ul class="nav-menu" id="nav-menu">
     <li>
         <a class="current" href="home">Home</a>
     </li>
     <li>
          <a href="cars">Cars</a>
     </li>
     <li>
          <a href="#">T&C</a>
     </li>
     <li>
          <a href="#">Prices</a>
     </li>
     <li>
          <a href="#">Services</a>
     </li>
     <li>
          <a href="#"">Contact</a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

And this is my jQuery code:

```
$('ul li a').click( function(){
     if ( $(this).hasClass('current') ) {
         $(this).removeClass('current');
     } else {
         $('li a.current').removeClass('current');
         $(this).addClass('current'); 
     }
});
```

As I mentioned above, for the last elements that have href="#" it works just fine, but when I press one that has a link, it just doesn't work.

Any suggestion is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the `href="home"` or `href="cars"` ones, the browser follows the link, loading a completely new page. When you click ones that just have an anchor (`href="#"`), that's navigation *within* the page, so the page isn't reloaded.

To highlight those navigation entries when the `home` or `cars` page loads, you'll need to run code on those new pages that finds and highlights them once the DOM is loaded.¹

For instance, on the `home` page:

```
$("ul li a[href=home]").addClass("current");
```

---

¹ If you're targeting even semi-modern environments, you can have top-level code in a `<script src="..." defer>` tag. In modern environments, you can use `<script type="module">` instead. In old environments, just put the `script` tag at the end of the body, just prior to `</body>`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, that worked like a charm. I realized it had something to do with loading the page but wasn't able to put the pieces together.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you meant, but I think you need to disable the default link click behavior with `event.preventDefault()`.

Declare **event** as an argument in the click function. Like this:

```
$('ul li a').click( function(event){
...
```

And write `event.preventDefault()` at the very beginning of the function.

Here is the complete code:

```
$('ul li a').click( function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
     if ( $(this).hasClass('current') ) {
         $(this).removeClass('current');
     } else {
         $('li a.current').removeClass('current');
         $(this).addClass('current'); 
     }
});
```

Comment: This worked for the nav bar and the class situation, but it had a weird behavior because I wasn't redirected to the pages anymore